# How can I parse an xml file from external folder in android studio?

Tags: android, parsing, directory

I have the following code but it doesn't work. When I work with the assets folder (InputStream is=getAssets().open("places.xml");) I have no problem.

My manifest.
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">

Thanks for help me.

```
private void parseXML() {
    File file = null;
    file = new File("/sdcard/Download/places.xml");
    if(file.exists()){
        Log.e("Message:", "File exists.");
    }else {
        Log.e("Message:", "File does NOT exists.");
    }
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory;
        parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = parserFactory.newPullParser();
        Log.e("Inside:","TRY");


        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(is, null);
        processParsing(parser);

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.e("Message:","Error1");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Message:","Error2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Was the permission requested and granted?

Comment: You have that problem on Android 10/Q.